# Duplicate a tab in Chrome without Reloading the Page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to completely duplicate the state of a current tab in Google Chrome?  I want an exact copy of the current state of the page without having to reload the page in another tab.

An example use case:

While browsing a "slideshow" on a news website, I want to preserve the current slide that I'm on, but create a duplicate so that I can continue viewing the next slide.  If I simply Right-Click and "Duplicate" the tab, the new page will completely Reload, reprocessing all of the Javascript and running the pre-slideshow advertisement again.

Comment: BTW when you duplicate a tab the normal way, it re-process the JavaScript and the DOM, but I think it does not make network requests.

Comment: Great point, @HaralanDobrev.  The reloading of Javascript and DOM may be a process that is unavoidable.  I'm not a security-guru, but I can imagine that it could cause sessionization issues if scripts on the page are not run.

But if it's okay to have multiple sandboxed tabs open on a secure page (e.g. Facebook or Gmail on https), then I think it should be trivial to create a "memory" copy of the current page.  Again, it might be impossible, but thanks for your comment -- definitely insightful that Chrome isn't throwing new HTTP requests out there on a Duplicate action.

Comment: While Chrome and IE9 do reprocess the HTML and JavaScript without reloading it from the server, Opera seems to be cloning the DOM. (A behavior that may go away once they switch to WebKit.) So I think that per @umterp09 comment, the answer to your question is: "no, not for now with Chrome".

Comment: Depends on how much work you want to do, but this is exactly the sort of thing that mutation observers can do.

Answer (score 4):

In short "NO" you can't.

I am not expert on this 
but a similar behavior can be achieved in some ways i know :

**Dump the whole DOM**

Never tried this though. You can convert the DOM to a string, pass it to the new window and then parse it as a document. This will let you lose your DOM events and State manipulation javascript. (But that's good for your case)

```
var dtab = window.open('about:blank', 'duplicate_a_tab');
dtab.document.open();
dtab.document.write("... yout html string ..");
dtab.document.close();
```

**Develop an extension**

Let the users continue on the current tab with the current state, your extension should be able to capture the screenshot of that area and open that screenshot in new tab. There are plenty of screenshot taking extensions are available in the market.

**If that website is your own**

You can develop your services that uses state locally like progressive web apps. Give a link separately to 'duplicate' which will eventually open the same URL in different tab with the same local state and with the flag do-not-sync.

> This will not work when the user uses browser inbuilt duplicate
>   feature.