# Duplicate browser tab ignores form elements current values

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser, tabs

### Issue

When you duplicate a tab in your browser, the current values of `form` elements are ignored. Tested in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Edge on a Windows 11 computer.

### Sample code & demo

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var range = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
var output = document.querySelector('output');
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var theme = document.querySelector('select');

function write() {
  p.textContent = textarea.value;
  output.value = range.value;
  span.textContent = checkbox.checked;
  document.body.className = theme.value;
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', write);
range.addEventListener('input', write);
checkbox.addEventListener('change', write);
theme.addEventListener('change', write);

write();
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
  gap: 1em 0.5em;
}

body.Dark {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
<p></p>
<input type="range">
<output></output>
<input type="checkbox">
<span></span>
<select>
  <option>Light</option>
  <option>Dark</option>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](https://labground.github.io/duplicate-browser-tab-ignores-form-elements-current-values.html)**

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Open the [demo page](https://labground.github.io/duplicate-browser-tab-ignores-form-elements-current-values.html) or create your own.
2. Change the `textarea`, `input`s, and `select` default values.
3. Duplicate the tab.

[image]

4. The `p`, `output` and `span` elements don't show the expected text content and the theme is still light.

### Question

1. Why does it happen?
2. What's the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate a tab in Chrome without Reloading the Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281000/duplicate-a-tab-in-chrome-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: @pilchard: Thanks, but that's not the same _and_ it doesn't provide a working solution.

Comment: _"Change the textarea and inputs default values."_ - typing data into those fields does not change their _default_ values, only their _current_ value.

Comment: What you want here, is simply not default behavior. If you need it, you will have to facilitate it yourself - store the current field values into `localStorage` whenever they change, and then when the second instance of your page loads in a new tab - read the values back from `localStorage`, and _set_ them for the input fields within that document.

Comment: To use localStorage to store value and restore it back on duplicate tab will work but if you do multiple duplicate tab then it will be difficult to find which tab value to be restore.

Comment: @CBroe: How about `sessionStorage`?

Comment: @Mori what about it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage: _"Whenever a document is loaded in a particular tab in the browser, a unique page session gets created and assigned to that particular tab. That page session is valid only for that particular tab."_ - so clearly not suited for what you want here.

Comment: @CBroe: From the same source: "Duplicating a tab copies the tab's sessionStorage into the new tab."

Comment: Okay, if that's the only use case you need it for (and not, say, if the user manually opens the same URL in a different tab), that will also do then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why does it happen?

Because the form in the browser tab doesn't store current value.

---

> 2. What's the solution?

Two solutions for solving that:

**1. Using Query Params**

Query params will store the current value as [URL Search Params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) so it can be accessed to refill data when duplicating the browser tab by `new URL(document.location).searchParams`.

Code: https://playcode.io/queryparams

Demo: https://queryparams.playcode.io

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Duplicate browser tab ignores form elements current values</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
      gap: 1em 0.5em;
    }

    body.Dark {
      color: white;
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
  <p></p>
  <input type="range" />
  <output></output>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
  <select>
      <option>Light</option>
      <option>Dark</option>
    </select>
  <script>
    var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
      var p = document.querySelector("p");
      var range = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
      var output = document.querySelector("output");
      var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var span = document.querySelector("span");
      var theme = document.querySelector("select");
      let currentParams = new URL(document.location).searchParams;

      function createQueryParams() {
        let newParams = new URLSearchParams({
          textarea: textarea.value,
          range: range.value,
          checkbox: checkbox.checked,
          theme: theme.value,
        });
        window.history.pushState("", "", `${location.pathname}?${newParams}`);
      }

      function applyQueryParams() {
        textarea.value = currentParams.get("textarea") !== undefined ? currentParams.get("textarea") :  textarea.value;
        range.value = currentParams.get("range") ? currentParams.get("range") : range.value;
        checkbox.checked = currentParams.get("checkbox") ? (currentParams.get("checkbox") == 'true') : checkbox.checked;
        theme.value = currentParams.get("theme") ? currentParams.get("theme") : theme.value;
        write();
      }

      function write() {
        textarea.innerHTML = textarea.value;
        p.textContent = textarea.value;
        output.textContent = range.value;
        span.textContent = checkbox.checked;
        document.body.className = theme.value;
        createQueryParams();
      }

      textarea.addEventListener("input", write);
      range.addEventListener("input", write);
      checkbox.addEventListener("change", write);
      theme.addEventListener("change", write);

      applyQueryParams();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**2. Using Session Storage**

Session storage will store the current value as [session data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) so it can be accessed to refill data when duplicating the browser tab by `.getItem` method.

Code: https://playcode.io/sessionstorage

Demo: https://sessionstorage.playcode.io

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Duplicate browser tab ignores form elements current values</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
      gap: 1em 0.5em;
    }

    body.Dark {
      color: white;
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
  <p></p>
  <input type="range" />
  <output></output>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
  <select>
      <option>Light</option>
      <option>Dark</option>
    </select>
  <script>
    var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
      var p = document.querySelector("p");
      var range = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
      var output = document.querySelector("output");
      var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var span = document.querySelector("span");
      var theme = document.querySelector("select");
      let currentSession = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data')) || {};
      
      function createSessionStorage() {
        let newSession = {
          textarea: textarea.value,
          range: range.value,
          checkbox: checkbox.checked,
          theme: theme.value,
        };
        sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(newSession));
      }

      function applySessionStorage() {
        textarea.value = currentSession["textarea"] ? currentSession["textarea"] : textarea.value;
        range.value = currentSession["range"] ? currentSession["range"] : range.value;
        checkbox.checked = currentSession["checkbox"] ? currentSession["checkbox"] : checkbox.checked;
        theme.value = currentSession["theme"] ? currentSession["theme"] : theme.value;
        write();
      }

      function write() {
        textarea.innerHTML = textarea.value;
        p.textContent = textarea.value;
        output.textContent = range.value;
        span.textContent = checkbox.checked;
        document.body.className = theme.value;
        createSessionStorage();
      }

      textarea.addEventListener("input", write);
      range.addEventListener("input", write);
      checkbox.addEventListener("change", write);
      theme.addEventListener("change", write);

      applySessionStorage();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    var p = document.querySelector('p');
    var range = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
    var output = document.querySelector('output');
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var span = document.querySelector('span');
    
    document.querySelector('textarea').value = 'Hello, world!';
    document.querySelector('input[type="range"]').value = 50;
    document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked = false;
    

    function write() {
      p.textContent = textarea.value;
      output.textContent = range.value;
      span.textContent = checkbox.checked;
    }

    textarea.addEventListener('input', write);
    range.addEventListener('input', write);
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', write);

    write();
```

```css
  body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
      gap: 1em 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
  




    <textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
    <p></p>
    <input type="range">
    <output></output>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the browser duplicates tabs, it will not fire the change event of textarea/range/checkbox. After, duplicating the tab, when the dom is loaded it will set its value. So, you need to provide some delay for your `write` function so the browser finishes setting the content of an element and then our write function will get the proper value of an element.

Updated code as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Duplicate browser tab ignores current values</title>
    <style>
      body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
        gap: 1em 0.5em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
    <p></p>
    <input type="range">
    <output></output>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span></span>
    <script>
      var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
      var p = document.querySelector('p');
      var range = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
      var output = document.querySelector('output');
      var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var span = document.querySelector('span');

      function write() {
        p.textContent = textarea.value;
        output.textContent = range.value;
        span.textContent = checkbox.checked;
      }

      textarea.addEventListener('input', write);
      range.addEventListener('input', write);
      checkbox.addEventListener('change', write);

      setTimeout(function() {
          write();
      }, 10);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**But Chrome is not copying state of checkbox in duplicated tab.**

To detect if tab is duplicated or not on Chrome/Firefox/IE(Chromium) you can use following JS:

```
// type value => details
// 0 => new tab
// 1 => reload tab
// 2 => duplicate tab
window.performance.navigation.type == 2
```

Comment: "But Chrome is not copying state of checkbox in duplicated tab." It doesn't behave consistently: sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Ok. We can't use localStorage. As If we duplicate the tab once then we get details from localStorage and set. After duplication, we change the value in duplicated tab and now we duplicate the tab from the first then localStorage will have the value from the last change so it will show the wrong data in the form.

Comment: Do we have the same problem with `sessionStorage`?

Comment: You can use sessionStorage. But if you duplicate tab and do changes and again duplicate original tab and you get data from duplicated tab. localStorage will be shared among all tabs of same domain.

Comment: It is more appropriate to call the function `write()` on the `window.onload` event. But this still won't set prop `:checked`, only update `textContent` in the elements.

Comment: I wonder why you've added default text contents to the `p`, `output` and `span` elements? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: @Mori It was already added to sample. But can be removed as write method will always call on page load. So it will update `p`, `output`, and `span`. Updated answer.

Comment: @imhvost It not working with onload. As browser sets intput/range value after load. So I used timeout.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can this delay be achieved with an `async` function instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: No as far as I know. If we add `async` to write function without `setTimeout` it behaves same as you have issue. If you add await while calling write function then it will stop working.

Comment: The delay `10` ms is just an arbitrary number and the actual time differs from browser to browser. Can the time a browser needs to load the current value into the duplicate tab calculated?

Comment: Its also depend upon how big your site is. Currently with your sample 10 ms works. But need to check with actual site and different browser and find an optimal value.

Comment: I checked - works normally on `window.onload`. So `setTimeout` is not needed. But this still won't set `:checked`, only update `textContent` in the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that the duplication of checkboxes and radiobuttons works reliably if the `value` of the checkbox/radiobutton is overwritten.

Both checkbox and text field are duplicated correctly, along with their textual representations, in the following example. The theme is also duplicated.

```js
function update() {
  for (var i of document.querySelectorAll("input")) {
    if (i.type === "checkbox" || i.type === "radio") {
      var value = i.value;
      i.value = "";
      i.value = value;
    }
    i.nextElementSibling.textContent = i.value;
  }
  document.body.className = document.querySelector("select").value;
}
```

```css
body.Dark {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="update()">
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="update()" /><span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="A" onchange="update()" /><span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="B" onchange="update()" /><span></span>
  <input type="text" onchange="update()" /><span></span>
  <select onchange="update()">
    <option>Light</option>
    <option>Dark</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: And what about `<input type="radio">` ?

Comment: It seems to be working. But it should be taken into account, that in real case `<input type="radio">` will have a different from `"on"` value.

Comment: Of course. I have edited my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the steps you provided on Firefox and Brave (based on Chromium) and they both **behave differently** on tab duplication.

- Firefox persists both "form" values and calls event listeners to reflect the change *(works only when you instead of `'change'` listen to `'input'` on your `<select>`. The reason is that `'change'` only fires when user actively selects a value, which doesn't happen during duplication.)*
- Brave keeps the "form" values but doesn't call the event listeners, so your output elements don't reflect the initial values (and the theme doesn't get changed).

This difference in behaviour shows well that the "tab duplication" **isn't standardized**, but rather a feature that each browser vendor implements the way it sees best. Each browser gets to decide how much of the original tab's state gets duplicated, which can have UX, performance and perhaps even security implications, and as my testing has shown the degree of duplication can differ substantially across browsers.

So as you can see, one **can't rely on a perfect duplication nor consistency** across different browsers. This means that you need some kind of persistency to make sure the values in the form get saved and reused in duplicated tab.

As others have already mentioned, you can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for testing or save the values in some kind of a database as a more robust solution.

Answer (score -1):

When duplicating a tab, input fields values  are saved, with exception `:checked` props.
As an option, you can save `:checked` props in `sessionStorage`.

For testing, I created a small [**example**](https://imhvost.github.io/76034491.html).
I divided the scripts into three parts:

1. save and restore `:checked`
2. initial show inputs values
3. show value after input change

I am adding all the code here:

*Update: added change theme.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Duplicate browser tab ignores current values</title>
  <style>
    body.dark {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="range">
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
      <span></span>
    </li>
     <li>
      <select>
        <option>light</option>
        <option>dark</option>
      </select>
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
<script>
 /* save and restore :checked */

const checkedElements = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"], [type="radio"]');
window.addEventListener('load', restoreCheckedState)

function restoreCheckedState() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('checkedState')) {
   const storage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('checkedState'));
   checkedElements.forEach( (el, index) => el.checked = storage[index] );
   // console.log('restore', sessionStorage.getItem('checkedState'));
  }
}

checkedElements.forEach( el => el.addEventListener('change', saveCheckedState) );

function saveCheckedState() {
  const checkeds = [];
  checkedElements.forEach( el => checkeds.push(el.checked) );
  sessionStorage.setItem( 'checkedState', JSON.stringify(checkeds) );
  // console.log('saved', sessionStorage.getItem('checkedState'));
}

/* initial show values */

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  inputs.forEach( el => showInputValue(el) );
  changeTheme( document.querySelector('select').value );
})

/* show value after input change */

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');

inputs.forEach( el => el.addEventListener( 'input', () => showInputValue(el) ) );

function showInputValue(input) {
  const span = input.closest('li').querySelector('span');
  if ( input.type === 'checkbox' ) {
   span.textContent = input.getAttribute('value') ? input.value : input.checked;
  } else if ( input.type === 'radio' ) {
   if ( input.name ){
    span.textContent = document.querySelector(`[name="${input.name}"]:checked`).value
   } else {
    span.textContent = input.checked;
   }
  } else {
   span.textContent = input.value;
  }
}

/* theme change */

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  changeTheme(this.value);
})

function changeTheme(theme = 'light') {
  document.body.classList.remove('light', 'dark');
  document.body.classList.add(theme);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`write()` must get called on initial site load.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
    write();
})
```

This should work.